# Can't Pass A Parameter for Datatable in Modal React JS

Tags: reactjs, datatable, undefined, modal-window

I have a datatable where it pops up a modal window if you select a row. I would like the modal window to display only a datatable of the selected row with additional details. However, passing in the selected row's ID for the modal window seems to not work and I don't know why? Or I'm not sure what is a better way to display information in a modal window?

**EDIT: I have discovered that if I replace this.state.TicketID with t and have t=0 then it also works so it must be something to do with calling this.state.TicketID within the x[]?

```
        const {id, created} = t
      })
      return (
        <div>
        <Modal isOpen={this.state.modal} toggle={this.toggleModal} className={this.props.className}>
          <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggleModal}>Selected Item </ModalHeader>
          <ModalBody>
            <Datatable>
               <table className="table table-striped my-4 w-100">
                  <thead>
                     <tr>
                       <td>Ticket ID</td>
                       <td>Created On</td>
                     </tr>
                   </thead>
                   <tbody>
                     <tr key={this.state.TicketID}>
                       <td>{this.state.x[this.state.TicketID].id}</td>
                       <td>{this.state.x[this.state.TicketID].created}</td>
                     </tr>
                   </tbody>
                 </table>
              </Datatable>
          </ModalBody>
        </Modal>
      </div>
      );
    }
```

TicketID is set in an outer function and is kept in the state object. It is updating as expected. I noticed if I do console.log({this.state.x[0].id}) then it works. However, if I do console.log({this.state.x[this.state.TicketID].id}), it gives an Cannot read property 'id' of undefined. Any help or new suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Why do you use state inside modal? I think you can only use props to do this.

Comment: what is the initial value of `this.state.x[this.state.TicketID]` ?

Comment: @EslamAbuHugair I set it to -1, but I checked with the console.log statements before it enters the Modal tags that it's set to 0 (that is the correct number because there's only 1 item in the datatable.

Answer (score 0):

actually for the current use case you don't even need a modal level state, so you just make the modal component as pure component(normal js function) and pass the values as props!

```js
    // pass these form the parent components 
    const {isOpend , onToggle, ticket:{id,created} ={}}= props // or from `currentActiveTicket` as described below 
    // if you mounting the modal element on the same datatable level 
    // and you only change the state of the parent component
    // when a row is clicked you can add the `currentActiveTicket` as an object 
   // value of what you want to display on the modal(make sense)
  })
      return (
        <div>
        <Modal isOpen={isOpend} toggle={onToggle} className={this.props.className}>
          <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggleModal}>Selected Item </ModalHeader>
          <ModalBody>
            <Datatable>
               <table className="table table-striped my-4 w-100">
                  <thead>
                     <tr>
                       <td>Ticket ID</td>
                       <td>Created On</td>
                     </tr>
                   </thead>
                   <tbody>
                     <tr key={id}>
                       <td>{id}</td>
                       <td>{created}</td>
                     </tr>
                   </tbody>
                 </table>
              </Datatable>
          </ModalBody>
        </Modal>
      </div>
      );
    }
```

or you have to maintain the props changing and reflect that on  the modal state

> for Example I have fallen into this kind of issues because I wasn't understanding  these concepts well enough - [`componentDidUpdate` check the references on this](https://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/life_cycle/update/postrender_with_componentdidupdate.html)